# I want to learn math from the beginning

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, precalculus

I finished high school 2 years ago and now I'm stuck in a university in Turkey. I am interested in learning precalculus, discrete mathematics, physics and chemistry.

Question: I need to learn math and physics from the bottom, and I mean by from the bottom all the basic material, possibly starting in from precaluclus and up to calculus, etc. I would also like advice for anything related to buying books or searching online for material. Anything would really be appreciated.

Comment: What are your end goals? This is very broad and up to interpretation.

Comment: I think the education system is screwed up. I think that in some countries, schools teach too much material and move on too fast before all the students have learned the basics properly, and a lot of students end up learning less as a result. If researchers aren't too busy doing other research, maybe they'll take the time for you to explain why you think the education system could be a lot better, and why Canada could fix up its education system by creating a government incentive to change the job market to move a lot of material to work place specific training, and spend more school time on

Comment: having students learn only simpler stuff in the beginning and explore their own interests based on it and end up really smart as a result and then wait until later to teach other stuff when they're smarter and can learn it more efficiently. Then they'll be so smart that work place specific training can train them better if they follow a proper organized plan on how they should all provide work place specific training. There will also be a general training course that teaches people the right complex concepts that will then enable them to be given work place specific training on a very complex

Comment: plan. Maybe after you do that hard research work, you could ask a question that's a fixed up version of this question showing what you discovered as a result of the research you did and why it was not enough for you to figure out the answer to your question. There's actually a good article about discovery learning at https://www.huffpost.com/entry/teaching-discovery-learning_b_856463.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give you some sense of how broad is your question, here is a small sampling of Precalculus textbook cover images:

---

[image: PreCalcBooks]

---

Perhaps start with this MSE question "[what is the best book for Pre-Calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/264591/237)."

Comment: THe question is nearing closure. But you're answer peeked my curiosity. Is there a definition of 'pre-calculus,' or is it just another term for Algebra2/Advanced Trig?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Good question! I've never taught it myself, but texts often include complex numbers, functions, probability & statistics, maybe even a little combinatorics.

Comment: At the university i'm studying thomas' calculus 12th edition i need something simpler to start with in order to be able to understand this book i hope this is enough answer and please excuse me i'm a bit lost

Comment: Hi Mohanad, I'd suggest simply watching Khan Academy videos and attempting the exercises. It may help to start with an Algebra 2 book, as those often cover a lot of material. My favorite Algebra 2 text is "Merill Algebra 2 with trigonometry," which is available on Amazon for only 15 cents: http://www.amazon.com/Merrill-Algebra-Trigonometry-Applications-Connections/dp/0675131189

Another alternative is, if you can afford it, to hire a tutor, who can look over the material in advance and help you with the gaps in your knowledge.

Comment: I like William Chen's [lecture notes](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/~maths/notes/wchen/contents.html) a lot. Well written and accessible, they cover a wide variety of topics starting from first year mathematics.